# Parse error: parse error, expecting in code ... Cannot spot it

Tags: php

I am getting: Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or`';'' in ... Error in the code below.

I have tried changing it but cannot spot what it is.

Can anyone spot this?

```
echo '<p><a href="#" onclick="Cart.add('name=".$name."','price=".$price."','image=".$image."');return false;">add</a></p>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not even with the SO text highlighting?

```
echo '<p><a href="#" onclick="Cart.add(\'name='.$name.'\',\'price='.$price.'\',\'image='.$image.'\');return false;">add</a></p>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape the single quotes with a backslash and you will fine.

```
echo '<p><a href="#" onclick="Cart.add(\'name=".$name."\',\'price=".$price."\',\'image=".$image."\');return false;">add</a></p>';
```

Go through the manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php to understand the details.

Comment: I doubt it, since the variables won't be replaced by their contents. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

correct code of your will be

```
echo '<p><a href="#" `onclick="Cart.add(\'name="'.$name.'",\'price="'.$price.'",\'image="'.$image.'");return false;">add</a></p>';`
```

but i dont know why you are passing name=$name
you can pass like $name too.
anyway may be that is your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to type *period* between string and variable !
Likes => `echo "your name=".$name."!";`
Not => `echo "your name"$name"!";`
Another question is, in php, each variable have add '$' before variable name.